# Importing CSV file into pgadmin but it pops out columns error

Tags: sql, import, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

[image: The error]
[image: The csv file head]

I want to import a csv file to pgadmin but it keeps showing

```
!columns
```

And in the columns tab there is nothing for me to select so I just cannot import the data.
In options tab, I select comma for delimiter.
Anyone know how to fix it?

I find similiar question but there is no solution to it.